# Why do I get blank space on top of the page?

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I am using jQuery mobile to make a mobile version of my site, but at the start issue appeared. On the top of the page I get 20px thick line of white space, and when I turn on inspect element I get " " characters before many div elements.

[image: Marked red is unwanted space]

Comment: Can we have the link to the page or a JSFiddle demo of your problem?

Comment: Sounds like a server side issue, not sure how you are rendering your HTML markup because image doesn't help that much

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a problem with the margin of some elements. Some elements have standard margins, like headings. This will cause the whole document to shift downwards. Try setting the style of every element, like the button in the left top corner and the heading in the menubar to:

```
margin-top: 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

the Default properties are causing a problem. you can override the default CSS properties.

```
body {
    display: inline;
}
```

or

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
```